# how to insert key-value pairs (NOT INSIDE A Datastructure) into redis from logstash

Tags: logstash

I understand I can push logs from logstash to redis, but out of the box, I think the logs into redis can only be pushed into a data structure like list..is there a way to push logs in "key", "value" format from logstash to redis..?
for example if logstash can pull a message(in json format) like this from its source

```
{"blahKey":{"utcTimestamp":"2014-11-12T10:00","somefield":"ABC","somefield":"DEF","somefield":20,"pid":182,"somefield":256,"Stay":0},"blahValue":{"someVal":1,"someVal":0}}
```

but needs to insert into redis in below format

```
"ABC.DEF.20.182.256.0", {"someVal":1,"someVal":0}
```

1.how do i parse the incoming message from `{"utcTimestamp":"2014-11-12T10:00","somefield":"ABC","somefield":"DEF","somefield":20,"pid":182,"somefield":256,"Stay":0} to "ABC.DEF.20.182.256.0"`
do i need to use grok filters, patter matching...please help me get started here

2.how do i manage to insert to redis as `"ABC.DEF.20.182.256.0", {"someVal":1,"someVal":0}`

Answer (score 0):

You can use the mutate plugin with its gsub method in the following way

```
mutate {
    gsub => [
        "fieldname", "regex for prefix clutter", "prefix character",
        "fieldname", "regex for delimeting clutter", "delimeter character",
        "fieldname", "regex for suffix clutter", "suffix character"
    ]
}
```